# Cluster Timestamps by Date

Tags: php, algorithm

I have an array containing timestamps. I would like to know how apps like Facebook etc. cluster posts. For clarity, imagine you have an array of timestamps and would like to group the timestamps by:

- Today
- This week
- This month
- Jan, Feb, March
- 2013
- 2012 and so on

It's important that the posts in 'This month' don't repeat in 'This week' and those in-turn don't repeat in 'Today'. Also, I have hardcoded Jan, Feb & March above. The script should technically detect the previous months in the year. I couldn't quite get around to writing an algorithm to achieve this fully. Here's what I have.

```
<?php
    $posts = array(
        array('post_id' => 7, 'timestamp' => '2014-04-20 20:17:49'),
        array('post_id' => 6, 'timestamp' => '2014-04-07 20:17:49'),
        array('post_id' => 5, 'timestamp' => '2014-03-17 20:17:49'),
        array('post_id' => 4, 'timestamp' => '2014-02-14 20:17:49'),
        array('post_id' => 3, 'timestamp' => '2014-01-09 20:17:49'),
        array('post_id' => 2, 'timestamp' => '2013-09-23 20:17:49'),
        array('post_id' => 1, 'timestamp' => '2012-09-23 20:17:49')
    );

    $today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $week_start = strtotime('last sunday', strtotime('tomorrow'));
    $month_start = strtotime(date_create(date("Y-m-d"))->modify('first day of this month')->format("Y-m-d"));
    $year_start = strtotime(date_create(date("Y-m-d"))->modify('first day of january 2014')->format("Y-m-d"));

    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        $item = strtotime($post['timestamp']);

        if ($item >= $today)
        {
            // Today
            echo '<br><br>' . 'Today' . '<br>';
            echo $post['post_id'] . '<br>';
        }
        else if (($item <= $today) && ($item >= $week_start))
        {
            // This week
            echo '<br><br>' . 'This week' . '<br>';
            echo $post['post_id'] . '<br>';
        }
        else if (($item <= $week_start) && ($item >= $month_start))
        {
            // This month
            echo '<br><br>' . 'This month' . '<br>';
            echo $post['post_id'] . '<br>';
        }
        else if (($item <= $month_start) && ($item >= $year_start))
        {
           // This year
           echo '<br><br>' . 'This year' . '<br>';
           echo $post['post_id'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
```

This script works until 'This month' and clusters the remaining only by 'This year'. I couldn't get around to sorting them by month and couldn't do the ones before this year. What  is the best way to achieve this level of clustering and to do it fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little rough but it should do the job.

You mention after January of the current year that the grouping should flick back to the year (2013, 2012, etc) - well, for a little flavour I also added in an additional limit of 'Last Year', just so you can see what is possible with [datetime formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

I also added in an additional post so you can see 'This Week' works correctly. I didn't thoroughly test the boundaries though so there is probably a little room for improvement.

```
$posts = array(
    array('post_id' => 8, 'timestamp' => '2014-04-20 20:17:49'),
    array('post_id' => 7, 'timestamp' => '2014-04-16 20:17:49'),
    array('post_id' => 6, 'timestamp' => '2014-04-07 20:17:49'),
    array('post_id' => 5, 'timestamp' => '2014-03-17 20:17:49'),
    array('post_id' => 4, 'timestamp' => '2014-02-14 20:17:49'),
    array('post_id' => 3, 'timestamp' => '2014-01-09 20:17:49'),
    array('post_id' => 2, 'timestamp' => '2013-09-23 20:17:49'),
    array('post_id' => 1, 'timestamp' => '2012-09-23 20:17:49')
);

// Set some limits
$limits = array(
    array('name' => 'Today',      'date' => new DateTime('today')),
    array('name' => 'This Week',  'date' => new DateTime('last sunday')),
    array('name' => 'This Month', 'date' => new DateTime('first day of this month midnight')),
    array('name' => 'Last Year',  'date' => new DateTime('first day of last year midnight')),
);

// Backfill months from this month to January of this year
for ($m = date('m') - 1; $m > 0; $m--) {
    $dateTime = new DateTime(sprintf('first day of %d month ago midnight', $m));
    $limits[] = array('name' => $dateTime->format('F'), 'date' => $dateTime);
}

// Sort the limits
uasort($limits, function ($date1, $date2) {
    if ($date1['date'] === $date2['date']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $date1['date'] > $date2['date'] ? -1 : 1;
});

// Find out where each post falls
foreach ($posts as $post) {

    $timestamp = new DateTime($post['timestamp']);

    // Default to the fallback (the year)
    $formatted = $timestamp->format('Y');

    foreach ($limits as $limit) {
        if ($timestamp >= $limit['date']) {
            $formatted = $limit['name'];
            break;
        }
    }

    echo sprintf("ID %s: %s (%s)\n", $post['post_id'], $timestamp->format('dS M Y H:i:s'), $formatted);
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully! I'm learning how you did it. How could prevent the name of the period from repeating as well? For instance, if there were two posts this week, only show the period name once instead of twice. I tried using a BOOLEAN switch but, it only complicated it even more and didn't display as I wanted.

Comment: Instead of `echo`ing out the data at the end of the `foreach` loop, you could append them to a data structure that is keyed by the period it fell into (i.e. group them). Then you can iterate over that additional 'grouped' data structure when you want to display the grouped data. Your method of using `bool` (I am assuming to mark if you had output a period label or not) is also sound, but I think it would rely on your data set (`$posts`) also being sorted.